# pass data through multiple InboundHandlers or OutboundHandlers in Netty

Tags: netty

The examples in the docs provide a Decoder->Encoder->BusinessLogicHandler flow. 
https://netty.io/4.1/xref/io/netty/example/factorial/package-summary.html

What I'm wondering is how you pass data to multiple InboundHandlers and multiple OutboundHandlers in a row.  From what I can tell, the Decoder decodes Bytes to POJO.  Then in the BuginessLogicHandler, which is a subclass of an InboundHandlerAdapter, it does a `ctx.writeAndFlush()`.  Is it this action that sends the data out and the Encoder (Outbound) gets the data to convert back to bytes.  If that assumption is correct, then how do you go from InboundHandler1->InboundHandler2 since I assume if you do a `ctx.writeAndFlush()` in InboundHandler1, then InboundHandler2 never gets the data because now the data is going back out of the pipeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call one of the fire*() methods of ChannelHandlerContext to forward an event to the next handler. And the data, that you want to forward to the next handler can be passed as argument of ChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(Object).

[Pipeline docs](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline.html)